# Selecting Python interpreter from WSL

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Windows 10 and want to set the the default VSCode interpreter for Python to be the same one used in my WSL 2 (Ubuntu), so that I'm always using "one Python".

When I click "Select Python interpreter" a prompt appears to find the interpreter path, but I'm not sure what the path would be.

Comment: Can I assume you have followed this guide?: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl-tutorial . You need to add the vscode extensions as noted in the guide.

Answer (score 31):

I think that, in order to use the WSL python, you need to be running VSCode in a WSL remote window. You need to install the Remote WSL extension first. Then, on the lower left there is a green button that will let you start a WSL window, or it will tell you that you are already in one.

[image: This shows that you are in a WSL window]

If you are in a WSL window, you should be able to select your python interpreter pretty easily. It will either automatically detect it, or you can run `which python3` in an Ubuntu terminal to get the path. If you want to navigate to a file on your Windows file system from within this window, look in, e.g., `/mnt/c/Users/<USER_NAME>`.

Comment: this needs to be modified to "which python3"

Answer (score 4):

Well probably late to the party but you can find Python you are using on your WSL2 with simple command:

```
which python3
```

It will show you where is the python placed.

Answer (score 1):

While above answers work, there are some related things to keep in mind here (or are at least worth mentioning):

1. I would recommend to create a virtual environment for your project. If you do so, its very easy to find the python interpreter in the bin folder of the venv. (If you want to "find" your WSL folder in windows. Just enter `explorer.exe .` in your terminal - it will open a windows explorer in the current location.
2. If you open the python interpreter selector form within VS Code on Windows, be aware that it opens a windows that let's you select "Executables" (meaning WINDOWS wxecutables):
   [image]

You will not be able to open your python interpreter located in your wsl like that, as the folder will be shown as empty.

Comment: How did you select a interpreter from conda env? I have wsl2 and vscode running but when I try to select the interpreter path ~anaconda3/env/bin it is showing no files match the executables. But there is a python file in bin folder.