# why my vscode does not have the same libraries installed in wsl?

Tags: visual-studio-code, pip, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using wsl and it runs codes in vscode pretty fine and I have different libraries which I installed through pip and conda in wsl but when I run that code using vscode itself it doesn't recognize the libraries or even pip itself.
I don't have any other environment.
I should add that I installed the packages globally using `conda install ...` or `pip install ...` in base environment and I only have base environment and I run my code through `code .` and I also have python and remote wsl extensions installed in my vscode.

what can be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much personal experience with this, but I found some useful information in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62514756/11810933) (even though it doesn't utilize conda), along with https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl-tutorial#_python-development.

I also found [this blog post](https://medium.com/@udiyosovzon/how-to-activate-conda-environment-in-vs-code-ce599497f20d) useful, even if it doesn't cover WSL.

In short, make sure you:

- Have installed the *Python* extension (by Microsoft) in VSCode.  This is critical for being able to detect and select the Python interpreter.  You don't mention having this in place, so I believe this is your likely problem.
- You have done this already, but including it for others who might read this later -- Install the *Remote - WSL* extension (or the *Remote Development* extension pack) in VSCode.
- You are also doing this already -- Start VSCode from inside your WSL distribution.  Alternatively, you can start VSCode from Windows and then select the *Remote WSL - Reopen Folder in WSL* from the Command Palette (also accessible from the "Remote" Status Bar).
- In VSCode, open the Command Palette with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, search for the *Python: Select Interpreter* command, and you should find your Conda environment in the list.

After selecting this, you should find that your project is using the interpreter and modules that you have installed via conda.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I did to overcome this issue is go to Extensions -> Local (You should have two tabs there, Local and WSL:DISTRO) DISTRO refers to whatever DISTRO you're using, you will see that some of the local extensions are disabled in the current workspace (WSL) and there is a little cloud icon in the `WSL:DISTRO` tab that says `install Local Extensions in WSL:DISTRO` once you click that it will let you choose which extensions to install and you should be good to go!