# Getting warnings while using django in vscode wsl

Tags: python, django

I'm using django in vscode in wsl. I'm getting continously warnings in importing packages like `from django.contrib import admin`, `from django.db import models` etc.
[image: this is how I am gotting warnings]

I tried to import python extension and set interpreter to version 3.10.12

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: I guess VS code is set to the local interpreter, not WSL. [Maybe this will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62514756/selecting-python-interpreter-from-wsl).

Comment: I got the answer I need to select a virtual environment interpreter.